# How to create unique folders per user in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, directory

### Laravel 4 Image Upload File In Unique Folder

How can I create per user a unique folder for uploading their images?

My code:

```
<?php
public function postFilesUpload() {
    $image = Input::file('image');

    $destinationPath = 'userdata/user/'; /* {user_id}/{time} */
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $filename = str_random(12) . "." . $extension;

    $image_upload = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    if ($image_upload) {
        return Redirect::route('get-media');
    }
} 
?>
```

I want to create a folder like this:

```
$result = File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory' . Auth::user()->id . "/" . time());
```

It should create this: `path/to/directory/{id}/{time}`, but it create a folder next to `path`.

Comment: And what exactly is preventing you to create the directory using the method you showed us?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

The solution is really simple:

```
$destinationPath = 'userdata/user/' . Auth::user()->id;
```

You **don't** need the `File::makeDirectory()`

Comment: A warning: If you have a lot of users, its dangerous to have a folder containing thousands of subfolders, it'd be better to structure your folder splitting the id like userdata/user/00/00/01/

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8

```
$fileName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();

$user->image = $request->image->move(('upload/'.$user->email ), $fileName);
```

Comment: Dear reza, welcome to SO,it would be nice to provide description with your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem Disks: you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver.

to make a new disk configure a new disk on the following file `root/config/filesystems.php`

```
        // CUSTOM STORAGE DISKS
        'attachment_profiles' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/upload_images'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

which will create folder under `root/storage/app/public/upload_images` when you save a file. make sure to link the storage using this command `php artisan storage:link` which will create a link to `public` folder

to store a file you can do the following thing

```
// if you receive a base64 image
Storage::disk('upload_images')->put($image_name_string, base64_decode($image_string));

// to store files
$image = $request->image;
$extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
$filename = str_random(12) . "." . $extension;

$filename->storeAs('/public/upload_images', $filename);
```

make sure to post your form with multipart attribue